# Adjust font size in map plots in ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot a number of points on a map of Germany, using the ggmap package, which works great. However, I would like to make some specific changes and do not know how to or if that is at all possible.

To make the maps, I do the following (d is a data frame with longitudes and latitudes):

```
map <- get_map(location = c(10.25828, 51.11484), zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain")
p <- ggmap(map)
p <- p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(6.09500,14.95306)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(47.39889,55.01250)+c(0,-0.1)) 
p <- p + xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude")
```

On that map, I then plot some points. Now, if I set zoom = 6 as above, then the map is very detailed, and lots of city names are printed, along with some white lines for the roads. This makes the map look a bit too "crowded". Here is what the map looks like: 
[image: zoom = 6]

The size of the pdf is also quite large which is not very practical if I want to have multiple maps.

On the other hand, if I set zoom = 5, then the background is less detailed, less roads etc are shown, and the file is smaller. However, the printed font of the city and country names is too large. Here is what it looks like:

[image: zoom 6]

So my question is: Can is somehow get a map with details as in zoom = 5, but with the font size of country and city names as in zoom = 6?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change from `get_map` to `get_googlemap`, you can pass a string to the `style` argument which will get passed to the Google Static Maps API. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro), and a crucial [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType).

I don't think you can change text size, but you can simplify roads and remove certain labels like so:

```
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(10.25828, 51.11484), zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain", 
                     style = 'feature:road|element:all|visibility:simplified&style=feature:administrative.locality|element:labels|visibility:off')
```

which returns

[image: simplified map of Germany]

If you want more labels, it's probably easier to insert them later in R. Adjust as you like.

Comment: works perfectly, thanks! I decided to go with `map <- get_googlemap(
  center = c(10.25828, 51.11484), zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain", 
  style = 'feature:road|element:all|visibility:off&style=feature:administrative.locality|element:labels|visibility:simplified'
)`

Comment: Another quick question: I might end up producing a whole lot of such maps. Do you have any suggestion (like selections for the `style = ...` option)  on how to keep the file sizes of the pdf's small?

Comment: The only real way is to downgrade image quality. There is a default in `get_googlemap` that sets `scale = 2`, which increases resolution. If you set it back to 1, you'll get a map about the quarter the size with half the resolution. Whether that's a practical option really depends what you're using the maps for, though.

Comment: Also, `visibility:simplified` doesn't seem to do anything aside from decrease the white drop shadow on the labels; you may be better off just going with just `'feature:road|element:all|visibility:off'`.

Comment: Thanks, the behavior of the `scale` option is a bit strange. Although the standard option should be `scale = 2`, if I specify `scale = 1` the returned pdf is the same as without specifying any `scale`. On the other hand, if I specifically set `scale = 2` the pdf has around twice the size.

Comment: Weird, mine defaults to `scale = 2` like it says. Maybe a version thing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know most map services include the labels in the rendered map tiles. I never had this problem in r, but with other map services.
Rendering with smaller labels using a customizable map service should be possible, but ggmap only offers CloudMade maps which might be a bit too expensive.

I would recommend using a different library if possible, maybe the one described at [r-bloggers.com](http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-package-full-o-pirates-makin-interactive-pirate-maps-in-arrrrrrstats/) they use a custom made map from [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/)
a free service (up to a certain limit) i would recommend.